# Export flowfield definition?

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I'm porting an old Navision 2009 solution to a new custom platform.

The Navision solution contains a lot of flow fields.
Is it possible to export all the flowfield definitions? So, not the actual result but the Name,Data Type, FieldClass and CalcFormula of the Flowfield.

Or where can I find these FlowField definitions in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Its impossible. The only you can do is search the tables that are related with your new platform, and filter the fields in NAV by FlowField. Then you can check one by one the relationships. Otherwhise, if you want to go faster, you can export that objects to text and then search the word FlowField.

Comment: We exported the object definitions to a text file. And wrote a text parser to grab the details of the flowfield